# Laravel DomPDF automatically rotate image to 90 degree. Image is coming from the twilio server. In html view it is working fine

Tags: image, twilio, media, laravel-dompdf

Laravel DomPDF automatically rotate image to 90 degree. In the html view it is working fine. Image is loading from the twilio server.

I have tried all the scripts from the internet but there is not any luck. Because image is coming from the twilio server. This is the main challenge.